# IR based tachometer with SD logger

Tags: c++, arduino, interrupt, sensors

I am a student during my Internship and I am trying to create a tachometer using an IR sensor. I will describe my program the problem.

Materials : arduino mega2560 ,IR sensor TCRT5000 Infrared Sensor Module - Line Track, LCD screen 16x2 , SD module MicroSD Module with SPI interface (for Arduino) and a couple of buttons.

The way my program works. As the program begins I initialize the sd module , the screen , the serial and my interrupts. When someone presses the first button an ISR routine sets a flag that enables the timer1 and the external interrupt for the IR sensor. Every time the IR sensor sends a pulse another ISR increments a counter. When timer 1 reaches a value (0.5seconds in my case) from another ISR sets another flag which allows a funtion on loop to stop the timer and the external interrupts from the IR sensor in order to calculate the RPM. I am using a homemade encoder disc with 4 pulses per revolution. The way I calculate the rpm=Tcounter60 /4where T is the period of the timer1 count and counter is the number of pulses i got in that time. Besides that within loop every second I call uppon another function that displays the rpm value on the LCD screen.

The problem is that i get almost 3 times less RPMs that what it should report.

I am hosting all of my code down below. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong ? Any advice is welcome around all of my code but my main concern at the moment is to get the correct value out of my tachomereter.

Thanks in advance :)

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <RTClib.h>


#define interrupts() sei()
#define noInterrupts() cli()

//debug
volatile int debugCounter=0;


//sd module
int CS_PIN=53;

File file;

//buttons
const byte toggleButton=3;
const byte dataSaveButton=18;

//sensor
const int pinIRd = 2;
const int pinIRa = A0;

//screen
const int rs=40, en=41, d4=42, d5=43, d6=44, d7=45; //lcd-arduino pins
LiquidCrystal lcd(rs, en, d4, d5, d6, d7);

//used for calculations
unsigned int rpm=0;
unsigned long lastMillis=0;
unsigned long lastMillisData=0;
unsigned long timeToDisplay=1000;
bool meterSet=false;


//volatile variables to be used inside int routines
volatile int counter=0;
volatile bool readyToCalculate=0;
volatile unsigned long lastInt_time=0;
volatile unsigned long currentInt_time=0;
volatile bool meterActive=0;
volatile bool writeToSD=0;
volatile unsigned int counterTable[10];
volatile byte counterTableIndex=0;

//measurement values
double firq=2;
unsigned int prescaler=1024;
unsigned long compVal=0;


void setup()
{
  displaySetUp();
  sdSetUp();
  pinSetUp();
  extIntSetUp();
}

void extIntSetUp(){
    //setting external interrupts
  EIMSK=0;//avoid unwanted interrupts
  EICRB=0x0F;//trigger INT4 INT5 rising edge
  EICRA=0xC0;//trigger INT3 on rising edge
  EIMSK=0x28;//only INT5 and INT3
}

void sdSetUp()
{
 //file test
initializeSD();
//createFile("test.txt");
//writeToFile("This is a sample text!");
//closeFile();
lcd.clear();
lcd.print("Sd initialized");
}

void displaySetUp()
{
    //serial and screen init
  Serial.begin(57600);
  lcd.begin(16,2);
  lcd.print("RPM counter v3.2");
}

void pinSetUp()
{
   //setup for the pins
  pinMode(pinIRd,INPUT);//attached to external interrupt device
  pinMode(pinIRa,INPUT);
  pinMode(toggleButton,INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(dataSaveButton,INPUT_PULLUP);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Sensor Init/zed");
}



void rpmMeterSetUP()
{
//initializing the timers
  compVal=(16000000*((1/firq)/1024));
  TCCR1A |=(1<<COM1A1);//reset OC1A on parity
  TCCR1B = 0;
  TCNT1=0;
  TCCR1B |=(1<<WGM12); //turn on ctc mode

  //set prescaler
  TCCR1B |=(1<<CS12) | (0<<CS11) | (1<<CS10); //set prescaler 1024
    
  OCR1A=compVal; //value at which the timer interrupts
  TIMSK1 |= (1<<OCIE1A); //output compare interrupt enable 1
  EIMSK=0x38;
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("setting up meter");
}




void loop()
{
  rpmCalc();

  if(millis()-lastMillis-timeToDisplay<=0)
  {
     lastMillis=millis();
     storeData();
     messagePrint();
  }
  
}

void storeData()
{
   if(writeToSD==1)
  {
    cli();
    char text [16];
    itoa(rpm,text,10);
    createFile("TestLog.txt");  
    writeToFile(text);
    closeFile();
    Serial.println("writeToSD run");
    sei();
  }
}

void rpmCalc()
{
   if (readyToCalculate==1)
    {
      readyToCalculate=0;
      byte tempReg=TCCR1B;
      EIMSK=0x28;//stops the external interrupts of int4
      TCCR1B=0; //stops the timer
      rpm=0; 
      rpm=((1/firq)*counter*60)/4;   //rpm=T * pulses *60 sec /4 pulses per revolution
      counter=0;
      TCCR1B=tempReg; //starts the timer 
      EIMSK=0x38;//starts the external interrupts int  
    }
    
}

void messagePrint()
{
   if(!meterActive)
   {
    stopDevice();
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("Ready to measure");
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("Press Start btn");
    
   }
   else if(meterActive && !meterSet)
   {
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("Measureing");
    startDevice();
   }
   else if (meterActive && meterSet)
   {
    // DateTime now = rtc.now();
  Serial.print("RPM : ");   
  Serial.println(rpm); 
  Serial.println(".....................");
  Serial.print("writeToSD : ");
  Serial.println(writeToSD);
  
  //Serial.println(now.hour(),DEC);
  
  //lcd
  lcd.clear();
  if(rpm>0)
  {
  lcd.setCursor(4,0);
  lcd.print("RPM  : ");
  lcd.print(rpm);
  lcd.setCursor(1,1);
  lcd.print("Logging : ");
  if(writeToSD==1)
  {
  lcd.print("YES");
  }
  else if(writeToSD==0)
  {
  lcd.print("NO");
  }
  }
  else if (rpm==0)
  {
    lcd.print("RPM : SLOW!!");
  }
 }
}

void startDevice(){
  rpmMeterSetUP(); //sets up timer and ir interrupts
  meterSet=1;
}

void stopDevice()
{
      EIMSK=0x28;//stops the external interrupts of int4
      TCCR1B=0; //stops the timer 
      counter=0;
      meterSet=0;
}

void initializeSD()
{
  Serial.println("init SD card...");
  pinMode(CS_PIN,OUTPUT);
  if (SD.begin())
  {
    Serial.println("SD card ready");
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("SD card failed");
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("Enter SD Card");
    return;
  }
}

int createFile (char filename[])
{
  file=SD.open(filename,FILE_WRITE);

  if(file)
  {
    Serial.println("File created");
    return 1;
   }
   else
   {
    Serial.println("File Error");
    return 0;
   }
}

int writeToFile(char text[])
{
  if (file)
  {
    file.println(text);
    Serial.println("Writing");
    Serial.println(text);
    return 1;
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Write Failed!");
    return 0;
  }
}

void closeFile()
{
  if(file)
  {
    file.close();
    Serial.println("File closed");
  }
}




  ISR (INT4_vect){
    currentInt_time=micros();
    if(currentInt_time-lastInt_time>1) //skips the counter++ if the interrupt occurs in less than 10milliseconds
    {
    counter++;
    lastInt_time=currentInt_time;
    }
  }

  ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
  {
      readyToCalculate=1;
  }

  ISR(INT5_vect)
  {
    meterActive=!meterActive;
  }

  ISR (INT3_vect)
  {
     writeToSD=!writeToSD;
  }
```

Comment: I do not analyze whole code but I see potential problem in this test. `if(millis()-lastMillis-timeToDisplay<=0)` All numbers are unsigned. So `<` doesn't make sense. If miss exact moment when ==0 test will always true. Better test is `if(millis()-lastMillis>=timeToDisplay)`. Another suggestion is remove write to SD card and remove all debug print in main code and make short debug message in ISR and compare with expected values.

Comment: Yes this will be changed but that wasn't the problem. This will still run when it is equal to 0. The problem was inside the rpmCalc function I should pass the counter value to a temp variable before doing my calculations. This was suggested in another forum about arduinos and was tested and confirmed about an hour ago.